# Cakephp 2.x validation fieldlist

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm programming a application using cakephp but the Method 'MyModel'->validates(array('fieldList) => array('myfield')) is not working. The related validation rule in my model is ignored.

My Controller function is as follows:

```
function _processaddbasic(){
$this->Caught->set($this->data);
if ($this->Caught-validates(array('fieldList' => array('type_id')))){
   return true;
}
return false;
}
```

My Modelpart is as follows:

```
public $validate = array(
'type_id'=> array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' =>true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
)
)
```

After executing the code with invalid (empty) data, the related part in my controller returns always true. So, where i'm wrong?

Comment: I figured out, that the 'required' tag of the type_id field inside the HTML code is missing. How can I ensure that the tag 'requried' is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions:

**Suggestion 1**

It looks like you have a typo in your code.

`if ($this->Caught-validates(array('fieldList' => array('type_id')))){`

should be

`if ($this->Caught->validates(array('fieldList' => array('type_id')))){`

(it's missing a '`>`')

**Suggestion 2**

If you use CakePhp 2.x it may be better to have

`$this->Caught->set($this->request->data);`

instead of

`$this->Caught->set($this->data);`

**Suggestion 3**

Your model may be "dirty" with data from other calls in your program. To reset it before adding data to it you'll have to call `create`; [see docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-create-array-data-array);

`$this->Caught->create();`

**Suggestion 4**

Check your Model class name and file name and make sure they are singular and that they match and that there are no typos.

Comment: I applied your proposals, but without any effect.

Comment: is the output of `debug( $this->request->data );`

Comment: I did. The array is empty and the model validation rules are still ignored. As posted above, I guess the problem is related to the missing 'requried' tag in the HTML code

Comment: ok, check suggestion 4 in the updated answer. Makre sure you Model is called Caught in a file called Caught.php and that it extends AppModel

Comment: It was a typo in the related form.ctp file, the Modelname was misspelled. Thank you for your support and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Check errors using `$errors = $this->ModelName->invalidFields();`

For ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html